# ruby cucumber click href in table

Tags: html-table, click, cucumber, href

I am new to ruby as well as cucumber, trying to automate. 
I need to click href link inside a table (Check1 and Check2). I tried:

```
@browser.link(:href => "http://googlenet.com.au").click  
@browser.table(:href => "http://googlenet.com.au").click
```

as well as:

```
@browser.find(:linkText => "Check1").click()   \\{capybara}
```

I am getting unable to locate element error or undefined method find while running.
How do I get it clicked? If I had to use capybara is there any config needed to be done in env.rb or any other file so as to include capybara gem?

My HTML LOOKS like:

```
<html webdriver="true">
<head></head>
<body class="background_colour" onload="loadHeader()">
   <div id="content_wrapper">
      <h2></h2>
      <br></br>
      <table class="menuTable">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td width="5%"></td>
      <td width="25%">
      <strong></strong>
      </td>
      <td width="70%"></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="menuTable">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="25%">
      <h3>
      <!-- B:Registration Link[START] Mod… -->
      <span class="black_font"></span>
      <a href="https://google.com/channel1_" target="_blank">Check1</a>
      <!-- B.Registration Link[START] Mod… -->
      </h3>
      </td>
      <td width="65%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="25%">
      <h3>
      <span class="black_font"></span>
      <a href="http://googlenet.com.au" target="_blank">Check2</a>
      </h3>
      </td>
      <td width="65%"></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="menuTable">
      <tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use

```
click_link('Check1')
click_link('Check2')
```

Take a look at this aswell

https://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-test-driven-development/rspec/capybara-cheat-sheet

Edit

With regards to your no method errors this is a basic setup i use that doesn't give me any problems

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
 gem 'cucumber'
 gem "capybara"
 gem 'rspec'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

capybara_drivers.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
 profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
 profile.native_events = true
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

env.rb

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Comment: Tanx for ur reply,But it is throwing an error NoMethodError: undefined method `click_link' for #<Page:0x41c7918>, Is there any thing need to be added in code so as to run capybara gem?,gem"capybara" is already there

Comment: What does your gemfile look like? Can you show more of your test setup? Are you requiring capybara?

Comment: gem.rb:source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "rake"
gem "cucumber"
gem "rspec"
gem "watir-webdriver"
# gem 'pickle'
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "rubyXL"
gem "roo"
gem "capybara"    and in env.rb require 'capybara' is present

Comment: gem_screen:http://i.imgur.com/u7CwFOn.png?1       and env.rb_screen:http://i.imgur.com/tHr2H1s.png?1

Comment: Ah ok, your using watir webdriver, try selenium webdriver instead

Comment: tried with selenium webdriver had to change the code like for eg:self.username_input.set username to self.username_input.send_keys username as it was throwing an error undefined method set...Still facing the same issue  undefined method `click_link' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fa322c00e browser=:firefox     gem has selenuim-webdriver and evn.rb has require 'selenium-webdriver'

Comment: How are you starting your capybara session?

Comment: pls take a look at thisscreenshots,almost every thing is there http://imgur.com/a/Ah1vg#0

Comment: tried with the above code ,Same error ::NoMethodError: undefined method `click_link' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fe3a2b90e browser=:firefox>

Comment: I even tried changing @browser.find_element(:class => 'search-button').click (which was working fine )  to @browser.click_link('search-button') (even tried click_button for this) same Nomethod Error is thrown,Seems like capybara initialization or something like version is wrong...  i am using ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32] (since heard that 2 and above 2 has some problems) and capybara (2.4.4)